# How to iterate through two list of custom objects and prepare a third one in C# using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the below 2 lists.
EmployeesDto List, AccountsDto List.
From these 2 lists, I need to prepare a third list: List.
just for simplicity, let's assume EmployeesDto has the following structure:

```
Class  EmployeesDto {
    public int EmpId {get; set; }
    public string EmpName {get; set; }
}
//And the AccountsDto is like:
Class  AccountsDto {
    public int EmpId {get; set; }
    public bool IsManager {get; set; }
}
// And LinkedEmployeesDto:
Class  LinkedEmployeesDto {
    public int EmpId {get; set; }
    public string EmpName {get; set; }
    public bool IsManager {get; set; }
}
```

Now I need to create the List based on the above two lists,the 'IsManager' property will be set from List where EmpId matches for both List and List t.
I can do it using foreach, but looking for more elegant way of doing it through LINQ.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are supposed to use [Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675(v=vs.110).aspx), but there are other ways too.

Comment: Is there a 1:1 correspondence between items in the first two lists?

Comment: @jmcilhinney, all distinct employees in the  AccountsDto List are present in EmployeesDto list.it's not exactlt 1:1 but atleast once!

Comment: You can use a LINQ join regardless or, if there's a 1:1 correspondence and both lists are sorted by `EmpId` then you can call the `Zip` extension method on either list. Note that the source lists don't have to be sorted to use `Zip` because you can include `OrderBy` calls too. I suggest that you look at least the first up and possibly the second too.  A LINQ join is much like a SQL join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can join using linq, to get third list as below

```
List<EmployeesDto> lstEmployeesDto = new List<EmployeesDto>();
        List<AccountsDto> lstAccountsDto = new List<AccountsDto>();

        var result = lstEmployeesDto.Join(lstAccountsDto,
                                   e => e.EmpId,
                                   d => d.EmpId, (employee, account) => new
                                   {
                                       EmpId = employee.EmpId,
                                       EmpName = employee.EmpName,
                                       IsManager = account.IsManager
                                   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you want to avoid Join. This example assumes you always have related data and a one-to-one relationship between Employees and Accounts. You might want to add custom checking to make sure.

```
List<EmployeesDto> Employees = new List<EmployeesDto>();
List<AccountsDto> Accounts = new List<AccountsDto>();

var linkedEmployees = Employees
                         .Select(e => 
                             new LinkedEmployeesDto
                                  { 
                                    EmpId = e.EmpId, 
                                    EmpName = e.EmpName,
                                    IsManager = Accounts
                                               .Single(a => a.EmpId == e.EmpId)
                                               .IsManager
                                  })
                         .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you the following 2 expressions based on your need.

```
    List<EmployeesDto> employees = new List<EmployeesDto>();
    employees.Add(new EmployeesDto { EmpId = 1, EmpName = "1" });
    employees.Add(new EmployeesDto { EmpId = 2, EmpName = "2" });
    employees.Add(new EmployeesDto { EmpId = 3, EmpName = "3" });
    employees.Add(new EmployeesDto { EmpId = 4, EmpName = "4" });

    List<AccountsDto> accounts = new List<AccountsDto>();
    accounts.Add(new AccountsDto { EmpId = 1, IsManager = true });
    accounts.Add(new AccountsDto { EmpId = 2, IsManager = true });


    // To get only those records which are in accounts list
    IEnumerable<LinkedEmployeesDto> linkedEmployees = employees.Join(accounts,
                                                                     employee => employee.EmpId,
                                                                     account => account.EmpId,
                                                                     (employee, account) => new LinkedEmployeesDto
                                                                     {
                                                                         EmpId = employee.EmpId,
                                                                         EmpName = employee.EmpName,
                                                                         IsManager = account.IsManager
                                                                     });

    // To get all the records from employee and set IsManager as false if record no in accounts list
    linkedEmployees = from employee in employees
                      join account in accounts on employee.EmpId equals account.EmpId into holder
                      from acc in holder.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      select new LinkedEmployeesDto
                      {
                          EmpId = employee.EmpId,
                          EmpName = employee.EmpName,
                          IsManager = (acc == null) ? false : acc.IsManager
                      };
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use Join in LinQ to compare for equality from the 2 lists and form the new list.

```
List<EmployeesDto> Employees = new List<EmployeesDto>();            
        List<AccountsDto> Accounts = new List<AccountsDto>();           
        List<LinkedEmployeesDto> linkedEmployees = new List<LinkedEmployeesDto>();
        linkedEmployees = (from emp in Employees
                           join acc in Accounts
                                on emp.EmpId equals acc.EmpId
                           select new LinkedEmployeesDto()
                           {
                               EmpId = emp.EmpId,
                               EmpName = emp.EmpName,
                               IsManager = acc.IsManager
                           }).ToList();
```